# How to do Google Recaptcha for react native mobile app

Tags: react-native, mobile, recaptcha-v3

We have a API for our backend. For the signin end point we have a Google recaptcha v3 field g-captcha-response from client which is required for the API Call. It works perfectly fine for the web app. We are now trying to use the same API endpoint for react native mobile app. In this case how will signin work without the recaptcha ?

I have never seen any mobile apps using recaptcha.

How do I go about this ?

Comment: have you mange to solve that?

Comment: We are planning to open the Web Login Page as a webview and then we will inform the React Native app about Success and allow the user to login. Yet to try this.

Answer (score 1):

[check this package](https://github.com/acsant/react-native-recaptcha) it's a react native wrapper for recaptcha v3

Comment: Thanks but the package is broken.

Answer (score 0):

Was able to implement that via [react-native-recaptcha-that-works](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-recaptcha-that-works)